# Keep recent searches in upper left pulldown on Android app

Tags: feature-request, search, android-app

There are a couple of searches I do routinely to follow SO questions of interest to me. It would be nice if there were any easy way to recall them. This would make the SE Android app of much more value to me.

Comment: Please do NOT approve junk edits!!

Comment: By "upper left pulldown", did you mean the one with "Questions, Tags, and Users"?